# How to Set a Parent Tables Updated Value in Materialized View Table with a Trigger if the Updated Value was not Null or Empty

Tags: sql-update, sql-server-express, database-trigger, materialized-views

I am using `C#'s EF Core` and a nice benefit of it is how I can dynamically update any attribute in the `Users` model with one method. I want to make a trigger to sense when my `token` attribute in my table `Users` is updated. That's pretty easy but, lets say `Users` have two ['sub-classes/materialized views'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSOq9.png)  `Donators` and `Staffs`. I want those following symmetrical attributes to match up when they are updated through a trigger.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Users](
    email VARCHAR(320) NOT NULL,
    password_salt varbinary(max) NOT NULL,
    password_hash varbinary(max) NOT NULL,
    token VARCHAR(320),
    /*d=Donator | s=Staff*/
    roles VARCHAR (2) NOT NULL,
    /*For: Donator */
    amount_donated MONEY,
    /*For: Staff */
    title VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (email),
);
/***Role Based Sub-Class Tables***/
CREATE TABLE Donators(
    email VARCHAR(320) NOT NULL,
    password_salt varbinary(max) NOT NULL,
    password_hash varbinary(max) NOT NULL,
    token VARCHAR(320),
    roles VARCHAR (2) NOT NULL,
    amount_donated MONEY NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES [Users](email)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE Staffs(
    email VARCHAR(320) NOT NULL,
    password_salt varbinary(max) NOT NULL,
    password_hash varbinary(max) NOT NULL,
    token VARCHAR(320),
    roles VARCHAR (2) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(256),
    created DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (email),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES [Users](email)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

To reframe from cluttering this question section I will not put my trigger since it does not work how I want at the moment because `Donators` attribute `token` does not match up when I update the `Users` attribute `token`.

My Code pertaining to this question can be found [here](https://github.com/StrawHatAaron/build-the-lanes-api/blob/master/InitDatabase.sql) (lines 248-366). Heads up Users have a few more subclasses. But, I just need to understand and find the code that allows `token` in `Staffs` and `Donators`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a [Ravenous Baboon's article](https://dev.to/ravenous_baboon/checking-if-the-column-was-updated-inside-sqlserver-update-trigger) is where I found the answer to my question. Here is a trigger of how I am going to keep my materialized view `Donators` up to date. Following along for any more inheritance I think is self-explanatory. (Feel free to ask if confused)

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER User_Updated_Check
ON [Users]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @email VARCHAR(320);
    DECLARE @old_roles VARCHAR (2);
    DECLARE @new_password_hash VARBINARY(max);
    DECLARE @new_password_salt VARBINARY(max);
    DECLARE @new_token VARCHAR(320);
    DECLARE @new_f_name VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE @new_l_name VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE @new_roles VARCHAR (2);
    DECLARE @new_amount_donated MONEY;
    DECLARE @new_title VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @new_type VARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE @new_created DATETIME;


    SET @email = (SELECT email FROM Inserted);
    SET @old_roles = (SELECT roles FROM Deleted);
    SET @new_password_hash = (SELECT  password_hash FROM Inserted);
    SET @new_password_salt = (SELECT  password_salt FROM Inserted);
    SET @new_token = (SELECT token FROM Inserted);
    SET @new_f_name = (SELECT f_name FROM Inserted);
    SET @new_l_name = (SELECT l_name FROM Inserted);
    SET @new_roles = (SELECT roles FROM Inserted);
    SET @new_amount_donated = (SELECT amount_donated FROM Inserted);
    SET @new_title = (SELECT title FROM Inserted);
    SET @new_type = (SELECT type FROM Inserted);
    SET @new_created = (SELECT created FROM Inserted);



    IF @old_roles != @new_roles
        BEGIN
            THROW 51000, 'The Roles need to match and cannot change', 1;
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END

    IF @new_roles != 'd' AND
       @new_roles != 's' AND
       @new_roles != 'e' AND
       @new_roles != 'a' AND
       @new_roles != 'sd' AND
       @new_roles != 'ed' AND
       @new_roles != 'ad'
        BEGIN
            THROW 51000, 'The Role entered does not exist', 1;
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END

    -- Donators
    IF @new_roles = 'd'  OR
       @new_roles = 'sd' OR
       @new_roles = 'ed' OR
       @new_roles = 'ad'
        IF UPDATE(token)
            UPDATE Donators
            SET token = @new_token
            WHERE email = @email;
        IF Update(password_salt)
            UPDATE Donators
            SET password_salt = @new_password_salt
            WHERE email = @email;
        IF Update(password_hash)
            UPDATE Donators
            SET password_hash = @new_password_hash
            WHERE email = @email;
        IF UPDATE(f_name)
            UPDATE Donators
            SET f_name = @new_f_name
            WHERE email = @email;
        IF Update(l_name)
            UPDATE Donators
            SET l_name = @new_l_name
            WHERE email = @email;
        IF Update(amount_donated)
            UPDATE Donators
            SET amount_donated = @new_amount_donated
            WHERE email = @email;

END
```